# what is the code to transfer a file using bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

i am trying to transferring a file with bluetooth between two device but not able to figure out any one can help me to build the code.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code or any suggestion of what is giving you problems, so the best I can offer is to recommend you take a look at [the documentation for Bluetooth services on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices)